# Why does the HTML validator give me an error about this HTML comment?

Tags: html, validation

Regarding comments inside of an HTML page:

For example:

```
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
    <!--
    <p><font size="4">--</font></p>
    -->
    </body>
</html>
```

Using http://validator.w3.org/check, I get the following error message. Does it make sense?

> Line 6, Column 21: invalid comment declaration: found character "<" outside comment but inside comment declaration
>
> `<p><font size="4">--</font></p>`
>
> Check that you are using a proper syntax for your comments, e.g: . This error may appear if you forget the last "--" to close one comment, and later open another.

Comment: If the validation is as strict as it is for XML, the "--" is not allowed inside an SGML type comment.  Sucks, but changing it to anything else works fine.

Comment: [em dash](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/em_dash#Noun) is [supported in HTML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references#Character_entity_references_in_HTML): `&mdash;`. Or Unicode ([code point U+2014](https://www.utf8-chartable.de/unicode-utf8-table.pl?start=8192&number=128)): "—"

Answer (score 10):

Yes, it makes sense.

To understand the error message, you have to understand the comment tag. It consists of three key parts, the `<!` that starts the tag, the `--` that starts and ends the comment, and the `>` that ends the tag.

When you put `--` inside the text of a comment, you actually end the comment part. The rest of the text until the end of the tag is invalid, as it's not a comment, and you can only have comments inside the comment tag.

You can also have more than one comment in the tag:

```
<!-- comment -- -- another comment -->
```

Comment: Ok, it does make sense now! I didn't know the comment tag had 3 parts. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

No, it does intuitively not make sense to most of the logical thinking humans, but the validator has it really right. The `--` denotes a comment delimiter. Also see [W3 validator bug 5555](http://www.w3.org/Bugs/Public/show_bug.cgi?id=5555):

> yes, really invalid. -- is a comment delimiter in XML.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's being confused by the two hyphens in the middle. The ones in >--<.

If you must have those, perhaps you could **substitute the escape character** `&#45;` for them.