# How to solve HTML comment which shows on website

Tags: html, blogger

OK this is very strange

I'm using this code

```
&lt;!--</body>--&gt; &lt;/body&gt;
```

and it gives me in the website this error --> like is not closing the html comment.
But when i remove or place it somewhere else is not doing his job (in this case deactivating default blogger js).

This is what i see in console
[image]

Comment: Can you provide a more complete sample...?? The snippet doesn't have quite enough information about the context...

Comment: @John Grischam, send blog url.

Comment: @Kwame Opare Asiedu sorry for the delay. The sample is everything on my blog https://www.kritere.com/ between <body> and </body>

Comment: @Muhammad Saleh my blog https://www.kritere.com/ Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

OK i found the solution. This is a very rare case so maybe will help somebody. In my case it was a html comment tag created by cookies script that interfered inside my html commenting creating this situation of double opening html comment tag : `<!--<!--\xc8 tua responsabilit\xe0 avvisare i visitatori dei cookie ...` This way the closing html comment remained open at the end making closing html comment tag visible. I added `&lt;!--</body>&lt;!-- --&gt;&lt;/body&gt;` closing this way the html comments tag and this worked deactivating the js and making invisible the html comment.
This [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3320350/why-does-the-html-validator-give-me-an-error-about-this-html-comment) post was very helpful

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the site's HTML... it seems you have two closing `</body>` tags...

From https://kritere.com

```
</body> --> </body>
```

Taking out the last body closing tag with the offending `-->` should solve the problem...

Comment: As i already explained in my question this </body> closing is specific to blogger and is included two times and once within html comments to deactivate blogger default js rising this way the speed of the website and making possible amp formation. Please let me know if you took this in consideration answering the question. Thnx

Comment: In your post you mentioned that this was your code `&lt;!--</body>--&gt; &lt;/body&gt;` which translates to `<!--</body>--></body>` but on the site I'm seeing `</body> --> </body>`. The first body closing tag does not seem to have the comment tag...

Comment: I think you are missing the initial `<!--` for the first body closing tag...

Comment: I updated my question even with a picture from the console. </body> tag is correct and the commented closing </body> does the job because deactivates blogger js but i still receive this --> closing html comment in my website visible.

Comment: You'll have to view the page's HTML to see what I'm referring to... Not the element inspector...